# Using .NET CodeDOM to declare and initialize a field in one statement

Tags: .net, codedom

I want to use CodeDOM to both declare and initialize my static field in one statement.  How can I do this?

```
// for example
public static int MyField = 5;
```

I can seem to figure out how to declare a static field, and I can set its value later, but I can't seem to get the above effect.

@lomaxx,
Naw, I just want static.  I don't want const.  This value can change.  I just wanted the simplicity of declaring and init'ing in one fell swoop.  As if anything in the codedom world is simple.  Every type name is 20+ characters long and you end up building these huge expression trees.  Makes my eyes bug out.  I'm only alive today thanks to resharper's reformatting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once you create your CodeMemberField instance to represent the static field, you can assign the InitExpression property to the expression you want to use to populate the field.

Answer (score 1):

[This post](http://weblogs.asp.net/okloeten/archive/2005/10/15/427549.aspx) by Omer van Kloeten seems to do what you want. Notice that the output has the line:

```
private static Foo instance = new Foo();
```

Comment: Link is dead. Here's a new one: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codememberfield.initexpression(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a const rather than static. I assume what you want is the effect of having a static readonly which is why you always want the value to be 5.

In c# consts are treated exactly the same as a readonly static.

[From the c# docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645749(VS.71).aspx):

> Even though constants are considered
>   static members, a constant-
>   declaration neither requires nor
>   allows a static modifier.